# Can you "Build a coffee"?

Tags: phrases, expressions

Would it be valid or invalid English, to use phrases along the following lines:

- Can you build a coffee?
- I'm building a coffee
- I'm going to go and build a coffee
- I built a coffee

Etc.

Comment: You can build a coffee shop/plantation/processing unit..is that what you are referring to?

Comment: @Josh61 No - just the coffee itself.. e.g. Putting instant coffee in a cup, adding water, stirring, and calling the process `building a coffee`. I'm trying to end a debate with someone who constantly says it like this.

Comment: That would be an unusual expression to say that you are making a coffee.

Comment: You might say it sarcastically, if preparing a cup of coffee requires an elaborate ritual - or a complex addition of ingredients. We have the expression 'build an ice cream sundae' - so it's not necessarily wrong.

Comment: I'm sure the terminology is used in some hoity-toity coffee houses.

Comment: ***Build a coffee:*** https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=build+a+coffee&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbuild%20a%20coffee%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Josh61 That nGram won't distinguish between "build a coffee table", "build a coffee house", "build a coffee colored coffin", etc.

Comment: @DanBron - but it shows that there is no *build a coffee* to drink.

Comment: I sometimes encounter (invariably, facetious) *build a **cigarette*** (or ***joint***) in the context of hand-rolling, but I don't think I've ever heard it used of a [cup of] coffee/tea. You do sometimes encounter [build a cocktail](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22build+a+cocktail%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) though, and what with all the "optional extras" in some cups of coffee (milk, froth, syrup extracts, chocolate shavings, etc.) I suppose it's bound to get used sometimes. Just not by the kind of people I mix with.

Comment: Yes, one **can** "build" a coffee -- never mind personal opinions of the lesser informed.

Comment: It's not typical, but the meaning is clear.  Your friend builds a heap of powders (instant coffee, sugar, nondairy creamer) then pours over water.

Comment: Am I alone in thinking it's a fairly routine matter to use *build* in the figurative sense here?

Comment: What is the native language of the person with whom you are debating (and, if it is English, what was the native language if his or her parents)?

Comment: @Robusto No, I think it's a reasonable extension as well. You can build your own sandwich/sub/burgers in many eateries nowadays, so I don't see why you shouldn't be able to build your own coffee in a posh cafe (especially if the barista has a beard and listens to obscure Faeroese whale-song music). If we're just talking about making a standard cup of coffee in a coffee maker or adding water to some Nescafé instant, though, you're definitely not building it (or even brewing it): you're just _making_ it.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet "_especially if the barista has a beard and listens to obscure Faeroese whale-song music_"... That got weird quickly.

Comment: @JoelCox It was my attempt at a pithy description of your typical hipster barista. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Coffee is *made* or *brewed* (in terms of the drink). It's also *planted* and *picked* (in terms of the plant).

Building coffee does not make sense.

Looking at [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=40635753), the only times *coffee* collocates with *build* is in the contexts of *coffee table* and *coffee break*.

Comment: There is a way to link to COCA results (I wrote up [a guide on Webapps.SE](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/79855/97102)), but I'm thinking it might be best practice to simply screenshot the results, cropping to or highlighting the areas of interest.  Anyway, that's what I plan on doing next time I want to reference it in an answer.

Comment: See my comment on the downvoted answer below. It is certainly possible to use *build* in a figurative sense regarding coffee.

Comment: +1 Unless, of course, you were layering it like a parfait, with the brew at the bottom, a carefully controlled upper region of cream, a dusting of nutmeg, a spritz of whipped cream, and a cherry on top. Voila! You have built a Cafe Supremo!

Comment: @bib Cherries on _coffee_? The bizarrities of this world never cease to bewilder me.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, you can say "I Built a Coffee"

The definition of "Build" from google:

> construct (something) by putting parts or material together.

synonyms are:

> make, construct, fabricate, form, manufacture, create, fashion, model, mould, shape, forge;

Defnition of Make:

> form (something) by putting parts together or combining substances; create.

- Can you make a coffee?
- I'm making a coffee
- I'm going to go and make a coffee
- I made a coffee

are all valid, id say yes, though it's unusual phrasing.

Comment: So you can *build a tea*, too!!

Comment: @Josh61 - Yes, but not a milk.

Comment: So I can *manufacture* an aperitif; *model* an appetizer; *forge* a lasagna; *mould* a cheesecake; *fashion* a digestif; and complete the evening meal by *building* some coffee. No, I don't think so. Just because *build* is a synonym for *make* doesn't make the two interchangeable.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Now I'm hungry! I'm definitely going to forge a lasagna tonight!

Comment: @DanBron  Yes, talking about beverages made me thirsty too, so I've just nipped into the kitchen and built myself a cup of tea.Oh, Aaron Cox, I don't mean to be mean. We're basically a polite bunch of users. Hey! Are you and Joel related?

Comment: Note that just as soon as everybody gets through downvoting this answer, some advertising copywriter somewhere is going to write a headline: "How To Build The Best Coffee Ever" . . .

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes we are - see my comment under the initial question saying I was hoping this question would end a debate with someone - that was referring to Aaron... And then he goes and answers the question and gets down-voted to oblivion. Couldn't have been better :D